# Ical in python - removing events

Tags: python, icalendar

I'm using an iCalendar package for python, you can see here:
http://codespeak.net/icalendar/

I'd like to delete an event. Can anyone think of a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if any one needs, this is function to delete component using icalendar library (http://codespeak.net/icalendar/) in python :

```
def del_component_with_uid(cal,uid):
    cal_str=cal.to_ical()
    component_find=find_component_with_uid(cal,uid)
    if component_find is not False:
        firstfind = unicode(cal_str, encoding="latin1").find(unicode(component_find, encoding="latin1"))
        export_cal(cal_str[:firstfind]+cal_str[firstfind+len(component_find):])

def find_component_with_uid(cal,uid):
    propert = uid
    for component in cal.subcomponents:
        for prop in component.property_items():
            if prop[0] == 'UID' and prop[1] == uid:
                return component.to_ical()
    return False

def export_cal(calendar_str):
    f = open('./Calendars/example.ics', 'w')
    f.write(calendar_str)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the codespeak package says nothing about a delete function, so unless there an undocumented one that works in-place on an existing file, you'd need to read a calendar file, enumerate its components:

```
for k,v in cal.items():
```

and write all the components except the ones to be deleted to a new file.

Since RFC5545 is a straightforward specification, it's probably safe to just delete a record from the cal dictionary directly.  But in general there could be dependencies between components or side effects (such as updating an index or checksum) so that manipulating the structure directly instead of calling a method could create internal inconsistencies.  Since this is Python, you could examine the add() method for side effects and create your own delete() method that reverses everything it does.

Comment: cal.items is an empty list. Not paricularly helpful.